# Search a MySQL database for superscript value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, datatables

I have some superscript (and other non-standard characters) in a table in my database.   They are stored fine and I can see them through PHPmyadmin.  However, if I attempt to do a search through PHP, it does not show any values and will hang when searching.

The url for the specific https://www.bowling-tracker.com/bowl/bowling-resources/bowling-ball-information

If you type 'Sword' in the search box, it should return 8 results but instead it hangs.

If I type

```
"SELECT * FROM `ball_model` WHERE NAME LIKE '%Sword%' ORDER BY `modelID` 
DESC"
```

into phpmyadmin I can see all the results.  The name in one of the results is Sword C³ and I'm sure the superscript is the issue as other searches work fine.

The actual SQL statement sent to the page is:

```
SELECT a.modelID, a.name, b.mfgID, b.name AS MfgName FROM ball_model a LEFT 
JOIN ball_mfg b ON a.mfgID = b.mfgID
```

which also works fine in phpmyadmin

So I'm quite baffled as to why it hangs at "processing" when trying to access records that have a superscript.

The table is set to utf8_general_ci as Collation and an InnoDB Storage Engine (in case that matters).

I'm using a pdo database connection which includes the following attributes:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DBhost;charset=utf8mb4", $DBuser, $DBpassword);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);}
```

The SQL is being executed server-side and I'm using DataTables to display the results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are using datatables plugin. This search is performed client side within the array of all the records printed and paginated client side. It's not an extra query

Comment: Check your error logs and your browser console.  Do you see errors?

Comment: It appears there are errors within DataTables (in Google DevTools) for this.  I'm not sure how to alleviate this though.

Comment: Lelio - The datatables plugin allows for server-side processing of queries.